# $_POST doesn't get the selected option value. Using PHP and MySQL to populate the HTML <select>

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save the selected value in post and access it from checkout.php. So far this method has worked for my other pages but here it just doesn't. This is how it looks like:

Source page of the value:

```
<form action = "checkout.php" method="post" >
        <select name='time' required>
            <option value="">-- Time --</option>
            <?php
            $result = getFreeAppointments($empid,$date);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
                <option value = <?php echo $row['StartTime'];?>><?php echo $row['StartTime'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input class="submit-block" type="submit" value="Checkout">
    </form>
```

Then in checkout.php it looks like this.

```
    if(isset($_POST['time']) && !empty($_POST['time'])) {
        $time = $_POST['time'];
    }
    else{
        $time = '10:00:00';
    }
```

If I echo the $time variable, I always get the default value '10:00:00'. Any idea what could cause this problem?

Comment: `<input class="submit-block" type="submit" value="Checkout">` No `name` attribute set so `($_POST['submit']` does not exist So `<input name="submit" class="submit-block" type="submit" value="Checkout">`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `name` attribute in `<input class="submit-block" type="submit" value="Checkout">`

Like :- `<input class="submit-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Checkout">`

```
<form action = "checkout.php" method="post" >
        <select name='time' required>
            <option value="">-- Time --</option>
            <?php
            $result = getFreeAppointments($empid,$date);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
                <option value = <?php echo $row['StartTime'];?>><?php echo $row['StartTime'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input class="submit-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Checkout">
    </form>
```

you have set `isset($_POST["submit"])` but in HTML the form, there is no data with this name.

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Problem is here
        insertKunde($_POST);
        if(isset($_POST['time']) && !empty($_POST['time'])) {
            $time = $_POST['time'];
        }
        else{
            $time = '10:00:00';
        }
}
```

Comment: Oops forgot to remove the section of the code, where I use the post method from an input on the checkout.php file. The problem code starts at if(isset($_POST['time']) && !empty($_POST['time'])) {
        $time = $_POST['time'];
    }
    else{
        $time = '10:00:00';
    }